# Esper arithmetic operation on date object

Tags: esper

I'm looking for a way to determine the time difference between two consecutive events that have a time event property with values like: 2016-08-25T13:05:06.953391Z. What would be the best approach here and what type do I need to use for the event schema. When using Esper EPL online I have tried to use Long or Date but then I get the following error:

Please check the EPL Module Text

Deployment failed in expression 'create schema StockTick(symbol string, price doubl...(63 chars)' : Error starting statement: Nestable type configuration encountered an unexpected property type name 'date' for property 'time', expected java.lang.Class or java.util.Map or the name of a previously-declared Map or ObjectArray type [create schema StockTick(symbol string, price double, time date)]

OR

Please check the Advance Time and Send Events text

Instruction at line 1 invalid event: Property by name 'time' cannot accept the assigned value: Invalid assignment of column 'time' of type 'java.lang.String' to event property 'time' typed as 'java.lang.Long', column and parameter types mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the EPL online tool web application, I don't think there is support for parsing custom date format. You can go with "long" and use the millisecond since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

Comment: Thanks! What do you figure is the best approach to determine the time difference between to consecutive events with for example the same unique id and only output the time difference? Can this be done with the prior or prev function?

Comment: There are examples for "prev" in the documentation

Comment: Thanks. I got it working using: select prev(0, time) - prev(1, time) as timeDiff from StockTick.win:length(2); Can you point me in the right direction with the following. I want to output the most frequent time difference per unique id once a day. How would I do this? Store the time differences in a window or table? Or use the enumaration method mostFrequent? Or a combination?

Comment: What you got working is probably not right because you want prev per unique id. I would insert the time differences into another stream (insert into). Then I think you want to count the time differences. This means you would want to round them. You can use count(*) and group-by on the time differences. Then I think insert that result into another stream. Than use a rank window with output snapshot every x minutes on that stream.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried the following: create schema StockTick(symbol string, price double, time long); insert into TimeDiffStream select prior(0, time) - prior(1, time) as timeDiff, symbol from StockTick; insert into CountStream select count(*) as count, symbol, timeDiff from TimeDiffStream group by timeDiff; select timeDiff from CountStream.ext:rank(symbol, 1, count);

Comment: But then I don't get the timeDiff with the highest count. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Correction for one statement: insert into CountStream select count(*) as count, symbol, timeDiff from TimeDiffStream group by timeDiff, symbol;

Comment: select * from CountStream.ext:rank(symbol, 1, count) output snapshot every 1 event // <-- this outputs not the insert+remove stream which you don't seem to need but instead the current rank